# Preappending line to new file in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Hi I've designed a integration flow in Spring Integration where I read from a file from SFTP and write to a file locally. I've set the fileExistsMode to APPEND-MODE but I'm wondering if it is possible to pre-append a string to the file before writing the contents of the remote file?

Example,

Remote file contains following content:

```
bla bla bla
bla bla
```

Local file will be written like this:

```
myLine <-- my pre-appended line
bla bla bla
bla bla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That fully looks like `interceptor` feature.

So, you implement `ChannelInterceptor.preSend()` for the channel on the `FileWritingMessageHandler`. In the code you check for the file `exists()` (based on the `message`).

If not, you create one and append that first like.

Return `message` as is and go to the `FileWritingMessageHandler`.